# Why Geohash named `xxxhash` when it's actually an encoding algorithm?

Tags: hash, encoding, naming-conventions, geohashing

```
A geohash is a convenient way of expressing a location (anywhere in the world) using a short alphanumeric string, with greater precision obtained with longer strings.
```

When I learn it the first time I was confused by its name. It's totally different to the other `hashing` algorithm, it keeps the information of the location. **It's actually not a `hashing` algorithm** but an `encoding` algorithm.

So how the algorithm named? Why it called `Geohash`?

---

**Comments**

1. To see the different between `Encoding` and `Hashing` you can click here: [Encoding vs. Encryption vs. Hashing vs. Obfuscation](https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/)
2. To see the Geohash algorithm in Java you can click here: [Geohash Encoding and Decoding Algorithm](http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/87283491372/geohash-encoding-and-decoding-algorithm)

Comment: [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) is just a mis-guided name the original author chose, you would have to ask him why he named it that way.